# Is there a limit to the number of calculations Excel will do when Calculations set to Automatic

Tags: excel

I've built a financial model with a large number of sheets (71) and formulas (currently 521,000) but I keep finding that values are not reflective of what the formulas should be calculating.

Even with Calculations set to Automatic Except for Data Tables simple formulas are not updating.

Is there a limit to the number of formulas Excel will calculate?
Is there a way to force every formula in a workbook to calculate?

TIA

Comment: CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + F9

Comment: Worth reviewing:  https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2012/02/16/excel-formulas-not-calculating/

Comment: Thanks Tim
CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + F9 was exactly what I was after.
Debra's blog was very helpful too.